# RubyMine hangs when starting debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, remote-debugging, rubymine

I am running OSC Lion, RubyMine 4.0.2, Ruby 1.9.3p125, and Rails 3.2.3.

Debugging has always worked fine for me in RubyMine. But today, my server crashed while using the debugger (when it hit an Exception breakpoint) and now I can no longer debug. When I click the button to start the debugger, there is a modal popup window titled "Connecting to the debugger" which contains the text ""Connecting to debugger using 10 sec timeout, please wait..." and a progress bar. After about 10 seconds the progress bar is 100% complete, but the popup window still displays, effectively hanging RubyMine.

The application does not appear to start (it does not respond to requests). The Debug console does not display. There are no new entries in the development.log file. The only way to get rid of RubyMine is to force quit it.

I've tried rebooting my computer, deleting the RubyMine cache files, reinstalling RubyMine, and reinstalling the debug gems (ruby-debug-base19x, ruby-debug-ide). Nothing works.

I am still able to run the application from RubyMine, without the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a solution: recloning a new copy of my project from the git repository. The  copy can be debugged without any problems.

It seems that whatever was causing the problem was in the project itself. I cannot imaging what the problem might have been.

Comment: I leveraged this suggestion and rather than re-checkout the project, I closed the project, wiped the ".idea/" folder, and reopened.  This also worked.  Thank you.